# Fecha formato ISO 8601 PHP

Tags: php, date, formato

buenas noches. Estoy necesitando darle formato a la fecha actual que se obtiene al ingresar a un PHP, el formato que necesito es ISO 8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz) por ejemplo, debe verse así:  "2020-05-30T23:59:59.000-04:00"

Busque pero no encontré la manera de obtener ese resultado, ojala puedan darme una mano.

Gracias,
Saludos.

Comment: Se puede apoyar pero necesitamos que leas [ask] y proveas un [mcve] por ejemplo como tienes el formato de fecha al inicio y lo que has tratado para formatearlo

Comment: ¿Con qué código estás trabajando y qué has intentado? Muestra al menos cómo recoges la fecha que quieres formatear. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para formatear una fecha con formato ISO 8601 se puede utilizar la constante `Datetime::ATOM` de PHP. Aunque PHP define la constante `ISO8601` esta no tiene el formato adecuado y se ha mantenido solo por compatibilidad con versiones anteriores. Ver [documentacion oficial al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.iso8601)

Ejemplo de uso:

```
$fecha_tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2021-06-25 11:35:55');
$fecha_str = $fecha_tmp->format(DateTime::ATOM);
echo $fecha_str;
```

La salida sería (suponiendo que estamos en horario CEST de verano que es GMT+2):

```
> 2021-06-25T11:35:55+02:00
```